# How can the type of $$, $1, $2... bison pseudo-variables be changed to GMP variables

Tags: c, calculator, bison, flex-lexer, gmp

I am writing calculator of simple expressions like 5^(3+2-sin(15)) in flex/bison. Source code can be found here - https://github.com/blueboar2/interval. For example, in interval.y there are such lines:

| EXP exp { $$ = exp($2); result = $$; }

| LN exp                { $$ = log($2); result = $$; }

| SIN exp                { $$ = sin($2); result = $$; }

It is all ok, since all of them ($$, $1, $2) - are doubles. But i want to build better calculator, with use of gmp precision library (for example, with 1000 decimal places). So, $$, $1 and others are not doubles now, and i need to change +/-/sin/exp to their gmp counterparts. How can i do so?

I've looked at gmp examples directory, where such calculator exist, but they simply incorporated a stack (of fixed size, sic), and stored there all numbers. I don't like this approach, partly because of fixed size stack (need glib to add "growing" array), partly because $$ = exp($2) is much better than "take number from stack, exponentiate, put to stack".

Comment: You'll have to replace the _double_ in your Bison file with the appropriate type for GMP numbers, and call the appropriate GMP functions.

Comment: I've updated files at GITHUB, changed double to mpf_t, but now other error occurs:interval.tab.c:1170:12 error: incompatible types when assigning to type "mpf_t" from type "struct __mpf_struct *". Why there is some struct, i don't know

Comment: The question may be deleted, as i already changed my calculator to use GLib dynamic arrays.

Comment: The gmp types are really pointers, but are declared as arrays, so you can't assign them or copy them directly.  This causes problems with bison as it wants to be able to copy `YYSTYPE` values with simple assignments.  One alternative is to define a struct with the GMP type in it -- something like `struct BigInt { mpz_t i; };` -- and use that as your `YYSTYPE` or in your `%union`.  Of course, you need to be careful that only one copy of given var exists at any time, or you may end up with dangling pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Bison/Yacc documentation, and look at `%union` or `YYSTYPE`.  If you are using Bison 3.0 or later, read `http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Semantics.html`.

Comment: Well, changing YYSTYPE to mpf_t doesn't help (you may see it as comment to initial question), today will try change api.value.type

Comment: According to gmp.h, `typedef __mpf_struct mpf_t[1];`, so both are the same, but somehow the compiler does not know that.  You probably lack a `#include <gmp.h>` somewhere, and I would expect `%code requires { #include <gmp.h> }` to be the appropriate place (http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Prologue-Alternatives.html).

Comment: No, it does not work. Same error. May be this happen because every gmp variable need to be initialized by gmp_init, and bison does not know, how to do this, so he can not initialize @@ or @1?